# Returning Nested Functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def raise_val(n):
    """Return the inner function."""

    def inner(x):
    """Raise x to the power of n."""
        raised = x ** n
        return raised

    return inner

square = raise_val(2)

cube = raise_val(3)

print(square(2), cube(4))
```

Outputs:

```
4 64
```

Can anybody explain to me how come `square(2)` knows that the argument passed is `x`?

Comment: because you can always access variables from outer scope and n is in the scope of `raise_val`, which is an outer scope of `inner` Here is more info: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python

Comment: What do you mean? `x` is just a name. Bottom line is you call `square` with the argument `2`. In that case `square` is equivalent to the function `inner` with the value of `n` being `2`. So the argument `2` of `square` is "passed on" to `inner`, which happens to be called `x`...

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What do you mean by "``square(2)`` knows that the argument passed is ``x``"? Argument binding works exactly the same for top-level and nested functions. ``square`` is an alias for a specific ``def inner(x):``, which "knows" its argument is ``x`` just like ``raise_value`` "knows" its argument is ``n``.

Comment: `raise_val(n)` returns a **function** of `x`, `inner(x)`, which has been specified by `n`. When you call `square(2)` you're really calling a specific version of `inner(x)`, which is equivalent to `raise_val(n)(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code uses the concept of lexical closures or closures.Closures are the function that remembers the parameters passed to their parent function.The more technical definition will be,Closures are the function that remembers values in enclosing scope even if they are not actually present in the memory.

```
#for example`
def outer(x):
    def inner():
        print(f"The argument passed to outer was {x}")
    '''Notice how inner() will grab the argument passed to the outer function'''

     return inner

value=outer(69)

print(value())
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: https://stackabuse.com/python-nested-functions/

Notice you "sends arguments twice" (not really): first in `square = raise_val(2)` and second in `square(2)`. What happens? The first calls return a function: you call to raise_val and it returns inner, which is a function. Now square variable actually holds a function. Second call, `square(2)`, just call to the function.

It's the same as:

```py
def a(x):
   print(x)

square = a 
print(square(5))
```

In this example, square holds a function. It's the same as in your code, since raise_val returns a function. Square holds `inner` method, and later it is been called. You send `x` directly: `square(2)` sends 2 for x of course.
A more interesting can be "how inner remembers `n`?", and as others mentioned in comments: it's manages variables of current scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, so it means that `square = raise_val(2)` here `square` holds the function `raise_val(n)` and when you pass arguments to `square` for eg. `square(2)` it knows that it is for `inner(x)`.

Comment: no. `square = raise_val(2)` does not the function `raise_val(n)`, it calls the function and hold what the function returns. If `raise_val` ended with `return 9`, variable `square` will hold 9. Since it returns a function, square holds a function. The second part of what you said is correct.